# convert zip file to ebook

Tags: ebooks, calibre, epub

I want to convert a zip file into an ebook using calibre 3.2.1 but the order of the chapters is in alphabetical order. You might be able to imagine that reading a book with the chapters in alphabetical order might spoil the reading a bit.

The table of content is accurate and links perfectly.
Unfortunately Calibre follows the order of the content.opf file in generating the chapter order and not the order of the table of content.
Can I set it to follow the TOC or convert the TOC into an accurate content.opf?

Answer (score 0):

Oke, If you remove the content.opf file it will automatically follow the order of the index page (I was very lucky to actually have an index page or else I would have had to sort this by hand)